# Upgrading software packages from CLI in Linux from some online repo

Tags: linux, upgrade, centos, rpm, repository

I am on CentOS and have tried the following:

```
[root@XMPP tigase]# rpm -Uvh MySQL-server-5.5.15-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm
error: open of MySQL-server-5.5.15-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory
```

SSH knocks people back to last century reminding me how flexible and unfriendly Linux can be.

How can I configure repos (in case they are not already)? How can I make RPM believe I would want it to upgrade from these repos?

Comment: Every time someone misspells it "Lunix" I think of that article that said it was the work of Soviet spy Linyos Torovoltos.

Comment: rofl had no idea, but I just like PUNs

Comment: "...Lunix...(is a) version of an illegal hacker operation system, invented by a Soviet computer hacker named Linyos Torovoltos, before the Russians lost the Cold War. ... These programs are used by hackers to break into other people's computer systems to steal credit card numbers. They may also be used to break into people's stereos to steal their music, using the "mp3" program. Torovoltos is a notorious hacker, responsible for writing many hacker programs, such as "telnet", which is used by hackers to connect to machines on the internet without using a telephone."

Comment: http://www.adequacy.org/stories/2001.12.2.42056.2147.html

Comment: also, in re: to your question, do you have that file in the current directory? since you're trying to run rpm directly on a package, it doesn't need to look in the repositories at all - it just installs the package you point it to.

Comment: no i don't have the file, I need to convince it to go fetch it from the internet.. and I would not want to use n tools to do a simple upgrade

Comment: @jcrawfordor +1 - way to out these crooks who would surely turn our children in to undercooked pesudo-steak sandwiches (ps - sorry I corrected his title to actually read 'Linux' - Lunix's good twin.

Comment: you need to use your package management tool, then, not your package installation tool. I think this is yum on centOS. so you should issue something like `$yum install mysql-server`. No need to give the architecture and version, yum figures that out itself.

Comment: yep, yum was it. Bad thing they don't have any newer mysql in whatever repo is configured on my workstation :| So I guess I'll have to wget the packages manually after all. Life sux, make that official so I can mark it answered, and -17 to Doc for mangling the question title ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `rpm` is an package manager. `yum`, is also a package manager but it solves package dependencies for you, and uses `rpm` to actually install packages.

Both can be used to install software, but in case a package has a dependency (usually they do) `rpm` will abort if those packages are not included in the command line, where yum will automatically satisfy and install all dependencies for you.

`yum` requires you to configure at least one repository from where to fetch software, where `rpm` needs direct access to the package (either a downloaded `.rpm` or provided from ftp/http).

So, the answer. Check if there is any repo configured

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d
```

If this returns files like `*.repo`, then something should already be there. If not, try:

```
# vim /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo
```

With the following contents (asuming you are running centos 6.0):

```
[centos]
name=centos
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.0/os/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.0/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Then (if there were repos configured or you just did it), run:

```
# yum search mysql
```

This should connect to the configured repos, fetch the list of available packages matching the pattern `mysql`. Once you have identified the package name (should be `mysql-server`) just:

```
# yum install mysql-server
```

If you want to install/update software, use `yum` if you dont want to mess with dependency solving